# Voltera equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Consider the Voltera integral equation:
$$ψ(x)=e^{-x}\cos(x)-\int_{0}^{x}e^{-(x-t)}\cos(x)ψ(t)dt$$

How can I solve this equation by converting it to a differential equation? 
The solution is $$\psi(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{e^{x+\sin(x)}}$$
I mean $$\psi(x)=\cos(x)e^{-(x+\sin(x))}$$

Comment: Have you tried derivating it ?

Comment: @Denis yes but I didn't get anything , I feel that I'm in huge storm

Comment: Are you familiar with the Leibniz integral rule? It is relevant to the differentiation of the second term.

Comment: @lan yes , I used Leibniz integral rule , but I didn't arrive to the correct answer , I feel that I'm in a huge storm

Comment: @Denis  see the answer above

Answer (score 1):

$$ψ(x)=e^{-x}\cos(x)-\int_{0}^{x}e^{-(x-t)}\cos(x)ψ(t)dt$$ 
$$\frac{e^x ψ(x)}{\cos(x)}=1-\int_{0}^{x}e^{t}ψ(t)dt$$ 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^x ψ(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)=-e^{x}ψ(x)$$
$$\frac{e^x ψ}{\cos(x)}+\frac{e^x\sin(x) ψ}{\cos^2(x)}+\frac{e^x ψ'}{\cos(x)}=-e^{x}ψ$$
$$\frac{ψ'}{ψ}=-\cos(x)-\frac{\sin(x) }{\cos(x)}-1$$
$$\ln|ψ|=-\sin(x)+\ln|\cos(x)|-x+\text{constant}$$
$$ψ(x)=c\:\cos(x)e^{-\sin(x)-x}$$
$$\frac{e^x (c\:\cos(x)e^{-\sin(x)-x})}{\cos(x)}=1-\int_{0}^{x}e^{t}(c\:\cos(t)e^{-\sin(t)-t})dt$$
$$c\: e^{-\sin(x)}=1-c\int_{0}^{x} \cos(t)e^{-\sin(t)}dt=1-c(-e^{\sin(x)}+1)\quad\implies\quad c=1$$
$$ψ(x)=\cos(x)e^{-\sin(x)-x}$$